# How to fix error can covert [NSDictionary] to NSDictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to display my json data on the tableviewcells. But, I am having problems appending the json result to my profile homemodel. I'm getting and error in my request manager which says cannot convert  [NSDictionary] to NSDictionary

import Foundation
class coreValueHomeModel {

```
//MARK: - properties
var total: String = "total"
var commentId: String = "commentId"

//construct
init(jsonData: NSDictionary){
    total = jsonData.objectForKey("total") as? String ?? "total"
    commentId = jsonData.objectForKey("commentId") as? String ?? "commentId"
}

//construct
init(total: String, commentId: String) {
    self.total = total
    self.commentId = commentId
}

//prints object's UserInformation
var description: String {
    return "total:\(total), commentId:\(commentId)"
}
```

}

import Foundation
class StrengthHomeModel {

```
//MARK: - properties
var id: String = "id"
var name: String = "name"
var description: String = "description"
var color: String = "color"

//construct
init(jsonData: NSDictionary){
    id = jsonData.objectForKey("id") as? String ?? "id"
    name = jsonData.objectForKey("name") as? String ?? "name"
    description = jsonData.objectForKey("description") as? String ?? "description"
    color = jsonData.objectForKey("color") as? String ?? "color"
}

//construct
init(id: String, name: String, description: String ,color: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.color = color
}

//prints object's UserInformation
var des: String {
    return "id: \(id), name: \(name), description: \(description), color: \(color)"

}
```

}

import Foundation
class ProfileHomeModel {

```
//MARK: - properties
var firstName: String? = "First Name"
var lastName: String? = "Last Name"
var location: String? = "location"
var title: String? = "title"
var score: String? = "score"
var received: String? = "received"
var given: String? = "given"
var coreValueResults = [coreValueHomeModel]()
var strengthResults = [StrengthHomeModel]()

init(jsonData: NSDictionary){
    firstName = jsonData.objectForKey("firstName") as? String ?? "First Name"
    lastName = jsonData.objectForKey("lastName") as? String ?? "Last Name"
    location = jsonData.objectForKey("location") as? String ?? "location"
    title = jsonData.objectForKey("title") as? String ?? "title"
    score = jsonData.objectForKey("score") as? String ?? "score"
    received = jsonData.objectForKey("received") as? String ?? "received"
    given = jsonData.objectForKey("given") as? String ?? "given"

    if let commentTotals = jsonData.objectForKey("commentTotals") as? [NSDictionary] {
        for commentTotal in commentTotals {
            let coreValue = coreValueHomeModel(jsonData: commentTotal)
            coreValueResults.append(coreValue)
        }

    }

    if let strengths = jsonData.objectForKey("strengths") as? [NSDictionary] {
        for strength in strengths {
            let strengthValue = StrengthHomeModel(jsonData: strength)
            strengthResults.append(strengthValue)
        }

    }

}

init(){
    firstName = nil
    lastName = nil
    location = nil
    title = nil
    score = nil
    received = nil
    given = nil
    coreValueResults = []
    strengthResults = []
}
```

}

```
import Foundation

class ProfileRequestManager {

    func parseJson() -> ProfileHomeModel  {
        var profileValue = ProfileHomeModel()

        let urlPath = "*********"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        do {
          let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                print(jsonData)
                let profile = jsonData!.objectForKey("profile") as? NSDictionary

            for profileInfo in profile! {
                print(profileInfo)
//problem here
                profileValue.append(ProfileHomeModel(jsonData: profileInfo))

            }

        }
    catch{
     print("Something went wrong while parsing json data fetched from the API")
    }
        return profileValue

        }
    }
```

And a sample of the data retrieved by `NSData(contentsOfURL:)`:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "Vignesh",
    "lastName": "Krish",
    "score": "126",
    "title": "Software Developer Intern",
    "given": "4",
    "received": "10",
    "commentTotals": [
      {
        "total": "4",
        "id": "8"
      },
      {
        "total": "3",
        "id": "9"
      },
      {
        "total": "2",
        "id": "10"
      },
      {
        "total": "1",
        "id": "11"
      }
    ],
    "strengths": [
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Analytical",
        "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Analytical theme search for reasons and causes. They have the ability to think about all the factors that might affect a situation.",
        "color": "9c0000"
      },
      {
        "id": "17",
        "name": "Focus",
        "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Focus theme can take a direction, follow through, and make the corrections necessary to stay on track. They prioritize, then act.",
        "color": "5c3a6e"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Communication",
        "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Communication theme generally find it easy to put their thoughts into words. They are good conversationalists and presenters.",
        "color": "da892f"
      },
      {
        "id": "29",
        "name": "Responsibility",
        "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Responsibility theme take psychological ownership of what they say they will do. They are committed to stable values such as honesty and loyalty.",
        "color": "5c3a6e"
      },
      {
        "id": "30",
        "name": "Restorative",
        "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Restorative theme are adept at dealing with problems. They are good at figuring out what is wrong and resolving it.",
        "color": "5c3a6e"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like the object is being serialized as a straight-up dictionary, not an array of dictionaries. Can you post a relevant snippet of the data you retrieve via `NSData(contentsOfURL:)`?

Comment: I posted the data I'm trying to retrieve in json format

Comment: Well, your data snippet pretty clearly shows your problem: `profile` is a dictionary. You're trying to cast it to an array of dictionaries. Change your cast from `[NSDictionary]` to `NSDictionary`

Comment: I made the changes as you mentioned. It gives me an error which says profilehomemodel has no member type append

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert an array (`[NSDictionary]`) to an individual `NSDictionary`, which is not allowed. Access the array you have to get the one you are looking for.

For example.

```
let myProfile = profile.firstObject
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `NSDictionary` not `[NSDictionary]`.

```
let profile = jsonData!.objectForKey("profile") as? NSDictionary
```

There are other problems with your code as well like the following which doesn't make sense and would cause an error.

```
for profile in profile {
    print(profile)
}
```

Comment: I made the changes as you mentioned. It gives me an error which says profilehomemodel has no member type append

Comment: @VigneshKrish There are several problems with your code and I'm can't fix everything for you. Hints: a JSON node will never be a `[NSDictionary]`, and you probably wouldn't want to access `NSDictionary` using a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

A valid json string can by an array or a dictionary. If you don't know what is the format of a json string, you should check for it type before manipulate its contents.

```
do {
    if let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
        //got a dictionary, do your works with this dictionary
    } else if let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSArray {
        //got an array, do your works with this dictionary
    } else {
        //is not a valid json data
    }
} catch let _error as NSError {
   //got error
}
```